# How to creat a View to impove the search engine of a website?

Tags: mysql

I have to do a search engine of website with a lot of access. This search will have to select information of 5 tables before result the records.

I could make 5 query as `SELECT * FROM table1 like ...`

But I was wondering if I could use an VIEW to do just one Query. (to get a better performance)

I have already checked informations about how to creat a view but its not so clear how to do que consult and how to manipulate the returned records.

Can anyone give me a simple example of how I should create (SQL Syntax) this VIEW and how I would do the search Query.

About the Tables as Example:

```
Table 1 id | title | description
Table 2 id | name | tags
Table 3 id | name | address
Table 4 id | product | price
```

I need to check all the fields.

Regards,

Comment: Can you tell us more about the 5 tables? Ideally, the columns, keys and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Views cannot return more than one result set. If you are currently returning 5 different result sets, one for each select statement, then a View is not going to help you.

If you are okay combining the result sets into one as shown below, then the View will help:

```
select title as col1 , description as col2 from table1
union
select name  as col1 , tags as col2 from table2
union 
select name  as col1 , address as col2 from table3
union 
select product  as col1 , price as col2 from table4
```

**Note:** If `price` is not the same data type as `description, tags` and `address` in `table1, table2,` and `table3` respectively, you'd probably need to cast it to the same data type as the other columns in the other tables. I am not sure what will be the coercion used by MySQL in this case but to be on the safe side, I would cast it.

On MySQL Views are created as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW test.v AS 
select title as col1 , description as col2 from table1
union
select name  as col1 , tags as col2 from table2
union --... etc
```

Then you can query it the same way you do it with a regular table; for example: `select col1, col2 from view_name where <condition>`

If you can't combine everything in one result set, a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) is the way to go. Just write a stored procedure that runs the 5 select statements in sequence and you call it from the front-end passing, I imagine, some sort of search parameter. The specifics on how to call this stored proc depends on the language/technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 5 tables are entirely unrelated - they're not a good candidate for creating a view. For a view to work, you'd need all columns in all tables to be of a similar datatype, and presumably "price" is a numerical column, whereas the others are varieties of varchar.

You could, of course, manipulate the "select" in the view to modify that, but then you end up with a view that makes no sense.

For instance (not checked for syntax, I haven't got SQL on my netbook)

```
create view SEARCH_VIEW
as 
select  'T1' as source, id, title, description
from t1
union
select 'T2' as source, id , name, tags
from t2
union
select 'T3' as source,  id, name, address
from t3
union 
select 'T4', id, product, convert(varchar, price) 
from t4
```

But then the resulting table would make no sense.

I'd stay with the separate queries; this also allows you to make decisions about relevance (a hit in "name" may be more relevant than in "tags", for instance).

Finally, you may need to look into free text indexing if you want to do text searches on large tables.